# Heisenberg Picture for 1D Simple Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The Halmiltonian for 1D simple harmonic oscillator is

$$
H = \frac{1}{2m}(P^2 + m^2 \omega^2 X^2).
$$

Show that in the Heisenberg picture, the sum of expectation

$$
\langle X_{t+\pi/2\omega}^2 \rangle + \langle 
 X_t^2 \rangle
$$

is constant.

Sorry I am an amateur and I have not taken any formal courses in quamtum mechanics. I am completely stuck.

Comment: Use the equation of motion for the Heisenberg picture operators to find $\frac{d}{dt} X = \frac{i}{\hbar} [H,X] = \frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{1}{2m}[P^2,X] = \frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{1}{2m} (-2 i \hbar P) = \frac{P}{m}$ and similarly $\frac{d}{dt} P = \frac{i}{\hbar} [H,P] = \frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{\omega^2 m}{2}[X^2,P] = \frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{\omega^2 m}{2} (2 i \hbar X) = - \omega^2 m X$. Hence $\frac{d^2}{dt^2} X = \frac{1}{m} \frac{d}{dt}P =  - \omega^2 X$. Therefore, the general solution for $X$ is of the form $X = A \cos(\omega t) + B \sin(\omega t) $.

Comment: @secavara That should be an Answer. (If you look in the browser "page source" you can copy your Mathjax.)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use the equation of motion for the Heisenberg picture operators to find

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} X = \frac{i}{\hbar} [H,X] = \frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{1}{2m}[P^2,X] = \frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{1}{2m} (-2 i \hbar P) = \frac{P}{m} \, ,
\end{equation}

and similarly

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} P = \frac{i}{\hbar} [H,P] = \frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{\omega^2 m}{2}[X^2,P] = \frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{\omega^2 m}{2} (2 i \hbar X) = - \omega^2 m X \,.
\end{equation}

Hence

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2}{dt^2} X = \frac{1}{m} \frac{d}{dt}P =  - \omega^2 X \, .
\end{equation}

Therefore, the general solution for $X$ is of the form

\begin{equation}
X = A \cos(\omega t) + B \sin(\omega t) \, .
\end{equation}

We can plug this solution in the equation for $P$ and find

\begin{equation}
P = - m \omega A \sin(\omega t) + m \omega B \cos(\omega t) \, .
\end{equation}

Notice that $A$ and $B$ are not completely arbitrary: since we must satisfy $[X,P] = i \hbar$, we must have $[A,B] = \frac{i \hbar}{m \omega}$. Hence, they certainly do not commute. Take this into account when computing $\langle X^2 \rangle$.